# HTML change css content

Tags: html, css

This is part of my css file:

```
.pricing .pricing-value .price:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'some text';
  top: 10px;
  left: -35px; }
```

I would like to change 'some text' into something different using style in my html file. Is is possible? I mean:

```
<span class="price" style='something_here'>
```

Comment: yes, HTML inserted style will be prioritised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`content: attr(some-attribute)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) to dynamically change content of `:pseudo` elements

```css
span:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
}
```

```html
<span data-text="Append"> TEXT</span><br/>
<span data-text="Another"> TEXT</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

nope, it's not. As `::before` is a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), and you can only apply styles directly on the element itself using the `style` attribute. But a pseudo-element doesn't exist when writing the DOM, it's added when the DOM is built.

You can however add another class and change the text there. Example;

```
.pricing .pricing-value .price.other-text::before {
    content: 'other text';
}

<span class="price other-text">
```